# remove text box drop down suggestions

Tags: html, css, textbox

I have a text input where people type and send text. I don't want the text box to have a drop down box with suggestions based on previous inputs. How do i remove this textbox drop down box? (I know its gonna be a simple 1 line of code but I can't find it :P)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try this attribute in your input tag:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Comment: this works in chrome for a calendar control where it adds a dropdown for previously entered dates. it actually obscures the calendar when it does this.

Answer (score 33):

This should do it

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score -5):

you can try this
`<input type="text" autocomplete="new-password" />`

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]